# How to add data to existing field in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have collection that look like this:

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("53ce11e7d0881d32d9fa935f"),
"username" : "hello_stack_overflow",
"Title" : ""
}
```

And i want to add to title each time a new data.

First Insert:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53ce11e7d0881d32d9fa935f"),
"username" : "hello_stack_overflow",
"Title" : "Batman"
}
```

Second Insert:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53ce11e7d0881d32d9fa935f"),
"username" : "hello_stack_overflow",
"Title" : "Batman","Avengares"
}
```

And so on...

Also, I want to add the new title to the relevant username. Someone know how to do that?

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("prog");
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("Users");
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("username", username);
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `update` and use `Document` instead `BasicDBObject`

```
 findDoc  =  new BasicDbObject("fieldNameToFindDoc", "fieldValueToMatch");
 updateDoc =   new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("title", "new Title"));
 collection.update(findDoc, updateDoc)
```

Comment: does it erase the last title or append to it? 
and i dont have update4, is it python or java?

Comment: It is Java. I misspelled it. It updates, if you pass proper match condition in findDoc